# how can i host a json file on artifactory, can artifcatory be used as a webserver

Tags: json, webserver, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I want to host a json file on artifactory repo.
Currently if i go to the link for the file it directly downloads.
But  i want it to be shown as a file like a webserver.

Is that possible in artifactory ?
Can it work as a webserver for hosting single files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve your use case, you need to enable content browsing option in your Artifcatory repository. You can find the details [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-OtherSettings):

Please be aware this may not work for all the file types(for json it should) as it's based on the mime types configured for the Artifactory application.

Answer (score 0):

You can view any file or artifact from the Artifactory UI (tree browsing) or with native list browsing.

See more information about file browsing [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Browsing+Artifacts#BrowsingArtifacts-TreeBrowsing) and [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Browsing+Artifacts#BrowsingArtifacts-ListBrowsing).